# How do I reapply after initially not replying to a potential employer after receiving an interview test?

Tags: interviewing

I had an interview with a company who sent me a design test a month ago and I did not reply.

Now I regret that decision and want another chance with them and I feel like I am stuck doing what I currently do. I do design but it feels like a sweatshop, At my interview I didn't feel like the new company had a similar feel but I felt intimidated so did not do the test and now I want to contact them.

Can I still message them and if so what do I say?

Comment: Could you clarify "_and im stuck with what I really wanted to do that time. Now i feel like i have no choice but to stick with what i do_". Do you mean you got scared and just stuck with what you were doing, but now you feel you have no choice but to move on? I feel this part may be quite important to an answer, as it's something you may need to explain to the company also (i.e. about why you didnt respond, but now are)

Comment: Cause currently I do design. That's my passion and I love doing it so i feel like im starting to be burned out since I do it in a daily basis. I don't wanna be a sweatshop for design. I also have another reason why I didnt respond to them. My boss was holding me into a one year contract so I cant leave. But turns out after I spoke to her, she's okay with me leaving anytime.

Comment: Okay so the new job is a design job, similar to what you currently do, but at the time you were a bit worried you didn't want to do it forever, but now you're very sure you want to do it forever (or at least for the foreseeable future)?

Comment: @Tas Y..yes? It's also because I don't know what else I can do and I only get accepted with design jobs. And also I thought that it might be a bit different with this new company since when I talked to them, it didnt feel like a sweatshop for design. But im scared too cause im intimidated with them since Im insecure with my design skills too. They're really good at what they do.

Answer (score 4):

**Email them:** What's the worst that could happen?

You have nothing to lose by asking, however you didn't reply when they sent you a test and you haven't been in contact since so you can't expect a guaranteed second chance or even a reply.

But as I say, damage is done; Explain to them your reasoning and that you're wanting another chance to complete the test and secure a role.

> Hi, I was sent a design test a month ago but I didn't reply because (reason), I'm sorry for the inconvenience but I was wondering if I could complete this test now and have another chance? If not I completely understand.

Something along those lines but make sure you make it more detailed and in depth (mine was just a brief idea)

Comment: Yes, if you feel uncomfortable making up a reason or telling them you got cold feet, just go with a personal reasons/issues outside my control type reason for not taking the test previously and assure them that it will not be an issue going forward. That way if they press you on the reason you can reveal it and you've  been truthful, and if they don't push for a reason you've not revealed something you're possibly uncomfortable about revealing.